# How to get first row and append it to jQuery DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm getting my first row:

```
var lFirstRow = self.table.fnGetData($('#' + self.idResultGrid() + ' tbody tr:eq(0)')[0]);
```

And trying to append to my table:

```
$('#' + self.idResultGrid() + ' tbody').append(lFirstRow);
```

Doesn't work, any idea why?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you mean it fails silently or throws an exception?  If an exception, what does it say?

Comment: Could you please add more code or error details to help you out..?

Comment: I found why it was not adding, cuz `lFirstRow` is an object, doesn't have a and html elements (<tr><td><input value = 'test'></td></tr>). And now, how can add those <table> elements to my object?

Comment: @WDS it does not simply do anything! I debug, it passes through, but nothing!

Comment: @SaviNuclear so do you have any idea how to add a <tr><td> to my object (`lFirstRow`), that later I could append it to my table? please!

Comment: What DataTables version  are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you should avoid manipulating the table directly unless really necessary and use appropriate API methods.

> **SOLUTION**

Use [`fnAddData`](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref) (DataTables 1.9) or [`row.add()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add%28%29) (DataTables 1.10) to add data to the table:

```
var lFirstRow = self.table.fnGetData($('#' + self.idResultGrid() + ' tbody tr:eq(0)'));
self.table.fnAddData(lFirstRow);
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xuah3x2m/) for code and demonstration.